# Finding the total

Tags: rally

I built a grid, and one of the columns is actual hours.  I was wondering how I could tally up the actual hours to find the total actual hours worked (obviously blank actual hours would be input as a zero).  I have tried using Ext.Array.each but I cant figure out what the parameters should be.  I also tried converting my grid into a table and then adding up all the cells but that has not worked either.  This is my load function:

```
//this.ownerComboBox = comboBox;

                    this.add({
                        xtype : 'rallygrid',
                        columnCfgs : ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'State', 'Actuals', 'Time Spent', 'Owner'],
                        context : this.getContext(),

                        storeConfig : {
                            model : 'task',
                            context : this.context.getDataContext(),
                            filters : [this._getStateFilter(), this._getStateFilter2()]
                        },

                    });
                    var config = {
                        columns : [{
                            key : 'FormattedID',
                        }, {
                            key : 'Name'
                        }, {
                            key : 'ScheduleState',
                        }, {
                            key : 'Actuals'
                        }]
                    };
                    var table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(config);
                    var vel = 0;
                    alert(table.getCell(1,3));
                    for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
                        vel = vel + table.getCell(i, 3);
                    }
                    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "The total is: " + vel;
```

When I run this code the console gives me the error Uncaught ReferenceError: rally is not defined (referencing the rally.sdk.ui.Table).  I know there is a better way to do it, but I am stuck.  Does anyone have any tips to get this table working or how I can use the Ext.Array.each?

Answer (score 0):

The `rally.sdk.ui.Table` is from AppSDK 1.x. This object doesn't exist in AppSDK2. The SDK2 equivalent is `Rally.ui.grid.Grid`.

I think you'll find the following example:

http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/example/custom-data-grid

Helpful. The `_onDataLoaded` method shows how to do some pre-processing on records from a `Rally.data.wsapi.Store` before using the output in the grid.

Comment: i think i understand what the example is doing, but i have 2 filters go to with my grid.  Should the creation of the store go in the launch and then have that call my two filters on a load or should create my filters and after the second filter, before i get to the code i posted above, should i create the store?

Comment: You can include your filters as part of the config in the WSAPI store. You can see how the filters are used in the docs for the store: http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.Store-cfg-filters

Comment: so i would use this code in the filter slot:        filters : [this._getStateFilter(), this._getStateFilter2()],
and i would include this function beneath the launch.  where would this go:this.add({
       xtype : 'rallyfieldvaluecombobox',
       itemId : 'stateComboBox',
       fieldLabel : 'Filter by State:',
       allowNoEntry : true,
       model : 'task',
       field : 'State',
       listeners : {
        select : this._onSelect1,
        ready : this._onLoad1,
        scope : this
       }
      }); and where would I still include the onselect function?